# How can I populate value of a hidden field in Django from the value of a range slider

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, hidden-field

So I am building an app that users are able to use a range slider to update a database with a new integer value. I have the slider which provides me with the integer value that I would like to return to the view, but I don't know how to return this value from the template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/

I looked at the documentation but I couldn't find anything regarding range inputs.

```
# forms.py

from django import forms

class UpdateForm(forms.Form):
    update = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(**something like:value='slider-input**}}))
```

```
# views.py
def home_view(request):
    form = UpdateForm()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form': form})
```

```
# index.html
...
    <form id="update-form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <div id="slider">
            <input class="slider-widget" min="0" max="25" step="1" value="0" type="range">
        </div>

        <div class="options">
            <a href="{% url 'main-home' %}">
                <img src="{% static 'main/media/cancel.png' %}" alt="cancel">
            </a>
            <button type="submit">
                <img src="{% static 'main/media/confirm.png' %}" alt="confirm">                
            </button>
        </div>        
    </form>
...
```

Comment: Could you post some details about your slider widget?

Comment: Yes. I cant add an image but it is just a range slider that goes from 0-25. I am building an app that multiple users can update line lengths so I need the value that the user enters with the slider to be returned to the view so that I can update the database to reflect the value @Chris

Comment: Is it a slider from some library?

Comment: <div id="slider">
        <input class="slider-widget" min="0" max="25" step="1" value="0" type="range">
</div> --> it is just a generic html range slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In it's simplest form you can take the slider value directly and do not need a HiddenField.

Your simple form

```
class UpdateForm(forms.Form):
    update = forms.IntegerField()
```

In your html template just make sure that you add the 'name' attribute to your slider and give it the same name as the field name in your form:

```
<div id="slider">
     <input name="update" class="slider-widget" min="0" max="25" step="1" value="0" type="range">
</div>
```

and in your view just process the form:

```
form = UpdateForm(request.GET or None)
if form.is_valid():
    slider_value = form.cleaned_data['update']
    # do somthing
```

Actually you do not really need a form for a simple case like this. You can also fetch the value directly in your view

```
slider_value = request.GET.get('update')
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! Yeah both work but I need a form since I will eventually need to pass more data back to the view. Thank you!